# SQL query to return table with if exists retun price 2 else return price 1

Tags: sql, if-statement, join, exists

I need help making a query to show the folowing result.

Supose I have tables:

Table 1

```
ProductId   Description
1           Banana
2           Apple
3           Melon
4           Orange
```

Table 2

```
ProductId   PriceNumber   Price
1           1             86
1           2             55
2           1             58
3           1             99
3           3             66
4           1             87
4           2             78
```

I need to show PriceNumber = 2 and if it doesn't exists show PriceNumber = 1

Wanted result:

```
ProductId   Description PriceNum    Price
1           Banana      2           55
2           Apple       1           58
3           Melon       1           99
4           Orange      2           78
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could you clarify why there are 2 values in the price number column?

Comment: The product can have more than one price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the setup of the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`ProductId` int, `Description` varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`ProductId`, `Description`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Banana'),
    (2, 'Apple'),
    (3, 'Melon'),
    (4, 'Orange')
;


CREATE TABLE Table2
    (`ProductId` int, `PriceNumber` int, `Price` varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO Table2
    (`ProductId`, `PriceNumber`, `Price`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, '7,86'),
    (1, 2, '3,55'), 
    (2, 1, '10,58'),
    (3, 1, '2,99'),
    (4, 1, '9,87'),
    (4, 2, '6,78')
;
```

Here's the actual answer in code:

```
SELECT  distinct(Table2.ProductId), 
        Description,
        PriceNumber, 
        Price 
FROM Table2
    INNER JOIN Table1
    ON Table1.ProductId = Table2.ProductId

WHERE (PriceNumber = 2) OR 
      (
          (Table2.ProductId not in (
                     SELECT ProductId 
                     FROM Table2 
                     WHERE PriceNumber = 2
                     )
           )
           AND
        (PriceNumber = 1)
       )
```

Here's a link to a sqlfiddle where you can play with the code:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/234ab/4/0

Comment: Your statment says that return price = 2 or price = 1 if count = 1. But I need to show price = 2 and if price = 2 doesn't exists show price = 1.<br> [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/234ab/1/0). Please note that product 3 has 2 prices but none is price 2.

Comment: Oh Ok, sorry about that. I'm updating it now

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're a SQL Master ;)